# Objects from API not rendered without clicking 'Load more' button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

I was creating a webpage with a 'Load more' button in React. Essentially, 10 objects are rendered at a time. However for some reason, the first 10 objects (I'm using JSON placeholder API here for reference) aren't rendered first-up. They require pressing the 'Load more' button. Here's my code:

```
const blogsPerPage = 10;
let arrayForHoldingBlogs = [];

function Loadmore() {
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchBlogs = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            const resp = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
            setBlogs(resp.data);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        
        fetchBlogs();
    }, [])

    const [blogsToShow, setBlogsToShow] = useState([]);
    const [next, setNext] = useState(0);

    const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
        const slicedBlogs = blogs.slice(start, end);
        arrayForHoldingBlogs = [...arrayForHoldingBlogs, ...slicedBlogs];
        setBlogsToShow(arrayForHoldingBlogs);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loopWithSlice(0, blogsPerPage);
        console.log(blogs);
    }, []);

    const handleShowMoreBlogs = () => {
        loopWithSlice(next, next + blogsPerPage);
        setNext(next + blogsPerPage);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Blogs blogs={blogsToShow} loading={loading} />
            <div id = {(next >= 100 || loading) ? "load-inactive" : "load-up"} onClick={handleShowMoreBlogs}><a id="load">Load more</a></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (next === 0 && blogs.length > 0 ) {
    loopWithSlice(0, blogsPerPage);
    console.log(blogs);
  }
}, [blogs, next]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This issue was real frustrating